# Music Practice, jamming and chord changes

Tags: theory, guitar, chords, practice

I do like jamming along with some music majorly softrocks and POP on youtube which have chords and lyrics with my accoustic guitar. I comfortably jam do okay in Key of G and still struggling a bit in Key of C. My challenge is when I get to bridge verse (Mostly shift to minor chords) I struggle. How can I work around this?

I play along with the music but I struggle to changing to minor chords and when the verse shifts to bridge. I would like also to start finger picking on those chord patterns to create dynamism in my playing.

My goal is learning to play music and master the fretboard to unlock my ability. I think my problem is getting too comfortable in key of G. I would love to jam along to any music maybe bar classical at this point. That means i would need to have skills on picking(I have basics), smooth chord changes in any key and maybe SOLOing later in the learning.
What schedule should I start with to make sure I become solid at ,chord changes,picking and SOLOing?

Comment: Work around? Don't play in C! Improve? Practice more in C! Sorry for the sarcasm, but you need to provide more details about what you do, what you struggle with, what you dislike and what you would like to improve, how do you practice this.

Comment: I play along with the music but I struggle to changing to minor chords and when the verse shifts to bridge. I would like also to start finger picking on those chord patterns to create dynamism in my playing.

Comment: Pick one song, start super slow. Until you can play it perfectly and relaxed. Increase tempo, and repeat. 

Find a good balance between having fun (jamming) and getting better (practicing)

Comment: I don't really see what your goal is, and without knowing this, it's hard to give directions. Decide what subskills you need, like knowing the chords for C major and how to switch between smoothly. Then ask how to learn them. This is WAY too open-ended.

Comment: @DaveJacoby Thanks for pointing this out. My goal is learning to play music. I think my problem is getting too comfortable in key of G. I would love to jamm along to any music maybe bar classical at this point. That means  i would need to have skills on picking(I have basics), Snooth chord changes in any key and maybe SOLOing later in the learning. I hope it gives you an insight.

Comment: There are great musicians who improvise almost everything they do. There are great musicians who have never improvised in their life. "Play music" is a _big_ goal. When you say G, is that rhythm? The three major chords: G, C and D? The corresponding chords in my C are C, F and G. Thus gives you your first barre chord with F, and with that, you can start unlocking the fretboard.

Comment: Welcome and thanks for asking! I've taken the liberty of moving some of what you've shared in the comments into the body of the question. In the future, when folks ask for more details, this is the best way to respond, by adding those details to the question itself.

Comment: Ironically, one of the first chords I taught myself on ukulele, because it involves 3 out of 4 strings being open, is the **Am** chord.

Comment: @CheruiyotAKirui "jam", "play along", "solo" that's all vague. You have folks here from jazz, rock, classical, folk, electronic, etc. What style, what song? Is there a player you would like to emulate?

Comment: @MichaelCurtis I like soft rock. I love Paul David(Youtube) but too advanced for me now.

Comment: @CheruiyotAKirui, I took a very quick look at Paul Davids channel. Nice stuff. But, I don't really see a _progression_ of lessons. It's more of a grab bag of posts. Look for a channel - or a method book - that organized in _progressive_ lessons. Just for a quick comparison, look at https://www.youtube.com/c/MartyMusic/playlists. Here has several lesson play lists. Some are named "easy/beginner" and he also has some organized by chord progression called "if you can play this you can play that." His channel is very much organized like a teacher's lessons. Look for that kind of stuff.

Comment: If you are teaching yourself, don't just settle on one single resource. Try lots of different things and compare them. Focus on the ones that work for you and dump the one that are not helpful.

Comment: @MichaelCurtis You are right. I do learn alot from Justin Guitar and Andy Guitar. They have organized lessons. For Paul Davids, I just like his inspiration and skills. I am feelin kind of at a plateau. I need something to push me more and enjoy playing.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like your problem is basically you are not good enough or quick enough changing chord shapes. It doesn't matter too much whether those chord shapes are major or minor, but you just happen to be weaker with, I guess, Am, Dm and Em.

Which is strange, as all three shapes, on open chords, are actually easier to get to than C, F and G open!

If you wish to continue in key C, which I don't consider the easiest to play in on guitar, then you just need to **practise** those changes a lot more.

Check between any two of those chords. Let's say C and Am. You shouuld notice that a coupe of fingers don't need to move at all as you change. That makes C>Am>C an easy change. Let's take Dm and G. No common fingers there - although if the G is G7, top string fret 1 stays for both.

So, what I'm suggesting is you get far better at each change - C>F>C. Em>F>Em, G>Am>G - there are plenty of chages, both ways. Examine your fingering - playing what a guitar site tells you *may* not be the best fingering for you. I often have at least a coupe of different fingerings for some chords, depending what precedes and what follows.

All of this for key C! Then the same concept needs applying to other keys. By using a capo, you could play along with songs in other keys than C, using those 'C' family shapes. And - getting used to playing in other keys, too, with their awkward associated chord shapes. There's still lots of work to do! Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Tim has said, not in contradiction to it, I'd add: Yes, it's good to practice jamming, and improvisation is its own skill. But when we improvise, we often simply re-use skills that we learned elsewhere in new combinations. When we practice scales, arpeggios, I-IV-V chord changes, etc., we're building a vocabulary that we can pull from "without thinking" when we need to.

So I'd say keep up the jamming, but also build up your core skills. Learn full songs, on purpose. Start easy, but try to keep challenging yourself with faster chord changes or more complex chords. Try familiar songs in unfamiliar keys. Practice scales. Most of all, as one of the comments suggested, practice undertempo and gradually build up your speed.